# May a builder skip "13" when numbering floors on a building or rooms on a floor

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, superstition

[Rabbi Kaganoff](http://rabbikaganoff.com/may-i-divine/) discusses the prohibition of *nichush* (superstitious omens) and starts the discussion with the question

> “May a frum builder skip the number 13 when naming the floors of a building?”

However, he does not explicitly answer the question. Consider that the clients of this builder, such as renters in an office building or clients in a hotel, would be reluctant to actually rent there. Would this indeed be nichush or would it be a legitimate (and mutar) business decision recognizing that others are superstitious.

An example of this line of reasoning is Yonasan and his armor bearer attacking the Pelishtim [Shmuel I 14:8-10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15843#v=8). Tosfos and the Ran (Chullin 95b) explain that Yonasan used the "omen" to reassure his armor bearer.

[Bottom Line Conjures Up Realty's Fear Of 13](http://realtytimes.com/todaysheadlines1/item/15685-20020913_13thfloor)

> Based on records of buildings with Otis brand elevators, as many as 85
>   percent of the high rises in the world don't have a 13th floor, says
>   Dilip Rangnekar, spokesman for the Farmington, CT-based elevator
>   maker.

Comment: How is this different from throwing a die into a trash can? It will show some number but you aren't using it as a superstition. Unless you are concerned for Lifnei Iver? Maras Ayin?

Comment: With "but the question is according to those who explain it as nichush," are you intending to limit the scope of your question? If so, that's a major limitation, and it should be highlighted at the top and probably in the title as well.

Comment: We have a Jewish version of this superstition. The number and the date written taf shin mem daled (tashmad - destroy) is written with the last two letters reversed.

Comment: @DanF I put the question on his web site http://rabbikaganoff.com/contact-us/comment-page-1/#comment-15846 I also put the reference about actual buildings into the question.

Comment: I live in a high rise without a 13th floor. There are many Orthodox Jews living in the building. When I moved-in, I have to admit that I found the missing 13th floor rather perturbing for a mid-century modern, Cold War era, tower-in-the-park development. I understand what "13" represents to some people but I just don't get why the concept appears to apply mostly to buildings and Fridays. (Friday the 13th perhaps should take-on  religious issues but not fear). Anyway, that's just me.  http://www.history.com/news/ask-history/whats-so-unlucky-about-the-number-13

Comment: @DoubleAA I really don't understand. NONE of the above answer the question either.  See your answer to me. Perhaps I am being obtuse; but I really do not understand.

Comment: @Oldwolfgilwell If you are referring to the above comments as not answering the question, that could be. Answers should be in answers. Comments are for clarifications, suggestions, etc (see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Alright I will comment.

Comment: Why is this tagged hashkafa? Isnt it a halakhic question of darkhei emori?